# Is there a way to know which applications track users?

Tags: android, location, privacy

I'm developing an Android application that shows on a map all locations gathered by the applications of your smartphone.
To do so, I'm using the [passive location provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER), which do not actively uses the GPS to obtain locations, but rather transmit those generated by other providers.

Problem with this provider is that it only returns [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location) objects, which (I think) do not contain any information regarding who asked for the location.

I understand that, from a "system" point of view, this information might be considered as sensitive, but I'm looking for a way to associate a location with the application that asked for it.

Comment: Your application should not know which application has requested and obtained which location.

Answer (score 0):

You must give permissions to apps (android 6 and higher), which wanna know your location. So, check application permissions.
Otherwise, i would recommend to use local proxy server(eg charles, fiddler) to track all network activity and hunt down applications what track your data.

Comment: I would like to develop an application for people to see which applications on their smartphones require their location, so unfortunately, I can't ask each and every one of them to install a proxy on his/her computer.

Comment: Really bad. But how about reflection? You can try to receive this information reflectively.

Comment: Do you think there's a way to "override" the LocationManager implementation thanks to reflection?

Comment: Yeap, you can, at least in your application. With custom class loader you can use your own class implementations for any system class.

Comment: Could you give me a code sample example? I'm very curious about this way to resolve the problem.

Comment: The author warns that this lib does not work with SDKs > 28 ; moreover it seems like the lib example samples are not working on my phone either (SDK 23).
In any case, thanks for your help.